# Pourquoi cette réponse a-t-elle été classifée comme insultante ?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Sur cette question: [Translation advice: passé simple or passé composé](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53289/translation-advice-pass%C3%A9-simple-or-pass%C3%A9-compos%C3%A9/53292#53292), la réponse proposée par 360smsapp a été supprimée par anonymous2 (un modérateur de ce site apparemment, mais que je n'ai jamais vu y participer). La raison indiquée de sa suppression est la suivante:

> This answer was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown

L'historique de révisions de cette réponse me permet d'y accéder, je vous retransmet donc son texte.

> French to English, the choice between the passé simple and passé composé tenses depends on the intended tone and context of the translation. In general, the passé composé is commonly used in English to express completed actions or events in the past. It corresponds to the simple past tense in English and is formed with an auxiliary verb (such as "have" or "be") and the past participle.

> The passé simple, on the other hand, has no direct equivalent in English. It is primarily used in literary or formal writing in French and may not have a direct translation in English. In most cases, when translating to English, the passé composé would be the appropriate choice to convey the past actions or events accurately. However, it's essential to consider the specific context and desired tone of the translation to ensure the most accurate and natural rendering in English.

Je suis d'accord que cette réponse n'est pas la meilleure que je n'ai jamais vue, mais c'est loin d'être la pire. En tous cas, à mon avis elle n'a aucune raison d'être considérée comme "spam, rude or abusing".

Ma question est donc: pourquoi a-t-elle été fermée ?

Comment: J'imagine que c'est parce que la version originale comprenait un lien vers un site pour l'apprentissage de l'anglais qui, selon l'interprétation, aurait impliqué une réponse ayant aucun objectif que d'en faire la promotion. Selon cette logique, même après qu'on y ait enlevé le lien, la réponse n'aurait servi à rien. Mais je ne fais qu'émettre des suppositions.

Comment: La question portait sur le français vers l'anglais, et pas l'inverse. Donc, la raison donnée n'est pas la bonnne tout comme vous remarquez.

Comment: @Lambie Et si tu avais regardé l'origine du lien dans la question (il suffit de survoler, pas besoin de cliquer pour leur faire faire du chiffre) tu aurais vu que ça n'avait aucun rapport avec le français. "spam" est exactement la bonne raison.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Anonymous2 participe certainement au Site FSE, même si ce n'est pas aussi régulièrement que d'autres. Par exemple [FYI](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/51488/is-there-a-french-equivalent-for-fyi-for-your-information/51489#51489) et [Intéressant](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/51054/1109)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En tant que modérateur qui a géré cette signalement, j'affirmerai simplement ce qui a été mentionné dans les autres réponses : la raison pour laquelle il a été supprimé en tant que spam était qu'il *y avait* un lien dans le message qui n'avait que peu ou rien à voir avec l'original question. De plus, ce n'était pas le seul message de l'utilisateur, qui spammait pour le même site web.

**Remarque pour les utilisateurs avec beaucoup de réputation** :

Comme mentionné [sur meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/333472):

> If an otherwise valid post contains an apparent spam link and especially if the bulk of the post is plagiarized from another post or from an off-site source, flag as spam (example). Do not try to salvage the post by removing the spammy content. If you're unsure, you can often find the original source with a Google search of its first sentence.
>
> (Traduction)
>
> Si une publication autrement valide contient un lien de spam apparent et surtout si la majeure partie de la publication est plagiée à partir d'une autre publication ou d'une source hors site, signalez-la comme spam (exemple). N'essayez pas de récupérer le message en supprimant le contenu indésirable. Si vous n'êtes pas sûr, vous pouvez souvent trouver la source originale avec une recherche Google de sa première phrase.

Cela pourrait devenir un peu déroutant à la fois pour le modérateur qui gère le signalement et pour les utilisateurs ultérieurs qui se demandent pourquoi le message a été supprimé si le spam est enlevé du poste. Aussi bien le laisser là ; il sera supprimé dans tous les cas.

Comment: Et merci pour ton travail régulier et visible de modérateur. Je viens d'ajouter quelque chose à ma réponse ci-dessous, peut-être qu'en tant que mod tu sais comment faire signaler le profil publicitaire.

Comment: Merci de vos paroles gentilles, c'est apprécié ! Ce n'est malheureusement pas possible de signaler un profil en tant que tel : la façon de faire est censé être de signaler l'un des postes de l'utilisateur avec un signalement de modérateur personnalisé. Vous avez effectivement raison par contre que le profil pourrait être enlevé ; je l'ai effacé et j'ai averti les modérateurs sur serverfault.

Comment: C'est grâce aux modérateurs (n'oublions pas *les* élections FSE au pluriel) qu'on trouve de telles solutions.  Bien dirigé et bien expliqué. Merci d'avoir fait ce qu'il fallait faire.  Que tu n'en aies jamais honte d'avoir fait ce qui est bien du boulot ici (et à vous tous les monos) !

Comment: @livresque Tu voulais écrire modos, c'est évident, mais juste au cas où tu ne l'aurais encore jamais entendu,  je te signale que monos existe aussi.

Answer (score 2):

La réponse n'a pas été classifiée comme insultante mais comme spam. Le but de cette réponse était uniquement de faire la promotion d'un site, ce qui est contraire au règles de Stack Exchange.

Son [auteur](https://stackexchange.com/users/28870795/360smsapp) a entretemps posé une question, effacée depuis, qui était de manière encore plus flagrante du spam (voir [réponse de None](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/943/1109)). C'est à la suite de cette deuxième "contribution" que j'ai flaggé la première car elle ne comportait de toute façon aucune information intéressante. Son style était par ailleurs celui de chatGPT qui a très probablement été utilisé pour rédiger la réponse, ce qui ne présente aucun intérêt pour Stack Exchange.

Comment: Merci, je comprends mieux !

Comment: T'as vu le profil qui est ouvertement de la pub ? Voir mon comment  à anonymous2.

Comment: @None Oui, j'ai vu son profil dont j'ai aussi mis un lien dans ma réponse. Je ne crois pas qu'on puisse reprocher à un profil StackExchange de faire de la pub (voir cette réponse de [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31197/why-is-the-f-word-still-allowed-in-profiles/31209#31209)) Le spam dans les réponses est bien sûr lui condamné.

Answer (score 2):

La réponse ne visait qu'à faire la promotion d'un lien vers un site en cachant ce lien à la toute fin d'une pseudo-réponse générique ; je suis la personne qui a retiré le lien afin de limiter sa visibilité et d'anéantir son dessein. À peu près au même moment, la personne a rédigé une question qui demandait pourquoi tel site l'avait motivée dans son apprentissage et le contenu de la question ne faisait que partager une « vraie » expérience pour faire la promotion du site en question. Dans le cas de la réponse, on peut noter qu'elle commence par « French to English » et qu'elle se termine par « ...to ensure the most accurate and natural rendering in English ». La réponse traduit des temps de verbe en français pour parler de traduction en anglais dans un texte en anglais, illustrant une grande confusion typique de l'utilisation de moyens de traduction automatiques. Le but du contenu était de camoufler du pourriel.

Answer (score 2):

Cette réponse a été mise par la même personne qui avait auparavant mis [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/53293/358) et que j'avais flaguée dès les minutes qui avaient suivi sa mise en ligne avec le motif "This is not a question but a text to promote a product." et dont j'avais  aussi demandé la fermeture pour que d'autres fassent le poids. Même lien dans les deux textes il est clair qu'il s'agit de promotion.

And to bring the matter further, since this company doing the promotion is involved in general learning un English (not just french) I doubt French language is the only SE site to have been spammed.

---

Shouldn't this [user's profile](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/32756/360smsapp) be removed? same on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/users/1030317/360smsapp) I don't have an account there. Could post on meta I suppose? But not really the place...